# How do I change the size of icons in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I'm building an app with Android Studio, and one of my activities (which lets the user draw on a canvas) has a 'toolbar', with things like 'Clear', 'Undo', 'Redo' etc.

I'm using the built-in icons for this - ie I go to the 'Drawables' folder, right-click, go to 'Add vector asset' and then select the appropriate icon.  I've figured out that I can change the size of the icon that gets added, but I can't figure out how to use that.

So, on a phone screen, I'd like to use the standard 24dp icons. However, on a tablet screen, I'd like the icon to be bigger, as they're a bit lost on the bigger screen.

I can't figure out how to do this, though, and I'm not even sure whether I'm using the right approach.  I know I can create different drawables sub-folders for different densities, but it's not so much the density that matters as the actual screen size.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You should increase the toolbar height, the icon will fit its container automatically.

In case, if you want to change the size of the icon, double-click the xml file of the icon and change the width and height inside. Do not touch the viewportWidth and viewportHeight parameters!

In general, you should not do this, as it wouldn't follow the google guidelines.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try increasing the toolbar height. I assume it's best to set that in dimens.xml for the individual screen sizes? I've figured out that I can create 'values-large' etc for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

app:itemIconsize="30dp"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).